# Haskell character encoding

Tags: haskell, character-encoding

I'm writing a Haskell program which generates an XML file. Apparently it is considered traditional to specify the character encoding in the `<?xml?>` tag. My question is, what's the best thing to do?

1. Use `hGetEncoding` to look up the file's encoding, and record that in the XML file header.
2. Use `hSetEncoding` to *specify* which encoding I want, and then hard-code that into the XML file header.

The first option appears to have the problem that I'd need a way to translate what Haskell calls the encoding into what XML calls it. The second has the problem that unless I can figure out what encoding all the other applications on my PC use, the file will be unreadable (except to web browsers).

All of which is slightly baffling, because I almost certainly don't even *need* Unicode anyway. I'm just writing plain ordinary English text with no special characters... (Ah, but the £ sign varies by encoding, doesn't it? *sigh*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you use one of the already existing XML libraries on Hackage, such as [xml-conduit](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/xml-enumerator), which will automatically handle encoding issues for you. In general, I strongly recommend outputting UTF-8 data.

Comment: The XML file is trivial enough to not really need a huge complex XML solution. I could explicitly request UTF-8; my only concern is that if I do that, the file won't open correctly in Notepad. (AFAIK, it defaults to whatever the Windows default encoding is...)

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid - if you are generating an xml file, then using a pre-made XML solution will probably be simpler (and safer) than rolling your own. Also, for the love of Monads, use Notepad++, or *something* slightly more powerful than Notepad.

Comment: For future visitors: It will open correctly in notepad; ASCII encoded as UTF-8 is still ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

In general: *You* decide what encoding you want to deal with internally in your app and what encoding you want to output. Don't leave it up to chance or the whim of some component. *Know* what encodings you're dealing with, *decide* what encoding you *want* to be dealing with and handle discrepancies as appropriate.

I'd say make sure your internal and external encoding is UTF-8 and convert any input that is in other encodings to UTF-8 before you do anything else with it. Whether you think you need Unicode or not, you have to standardize on *something*, and unless you have concrete reasons against using Unicode it's the most versatile choice that won't get you into trouble later.

Comment: The _internal_ encoding is a non-issue; the Haskell I/O libraries automatically handle converting everything to Haskell's internal character encoding, which is essentially UTF32. Those same I/O libraries will encode my output in whatever way I ask for. The question is, what to ask for. (Or whether to just ask what the default choice was.)

Comment: Also, UTF-8 and UTF-16 are the only encodings that the XML standard requires support for, so it makes a lot of sense to just standardize on one of those.

Comment: @Math Fair enough, all the more reason to go with Unicode. I'm not that much into Haskell to know how it handles encodings, this is more of a generalized statement. :)

Comment: @hammar I think it specifies support is required for UTF-32 as well. Though I don't think I've ever seen a tool produce UTF-32 by default. And don't forget that for UTF-16 and 32, you have big and little endian variants.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for option #2 - better to control the encoding used than rely on default behaviour.

And as Joel Spolsky said: [*there ain't no such thing as plain text*](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/printerFriendly/articles/Unicode.html).